# How do I add a mouse click position to a list in tkinter?

Tags: python, events, tkinter, click

I am trying to create a list of mouse clicks using tkinter in python. Here is what I have so far:

```
def main():

    master = Tk()
    w = Canvas(master, width=400, height=400)
    w.pack()
    w.create_line(0, 200, 400, 200)
    w.create_line(200, 0, 200, 400)
    circle = w.create_oval(190, 190, 210, 210,
                               fill='blue', width=1)

    w.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: left_mouse_click(event))


    mainloop()

def left_mouse_click(event, robot, speed):

    # Should create and return a list
    canvas = event.widget
    canvas.create_oval(event.x - 10, event.y - 10,
                       event.x + 10, event.y + 10,
                       fill='red', width=1)
```

How can I save each and every event.x and event.y into separate lists?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a list to add to. I called it `clicks`.

So `main` will look like this:

```
def main():

    master = Tk()
    w = Canvas(master, width=400, height=400)
    w.pack()
    w.create_line(0, 200, 400, 200)
    w.create_line(200, 0, 200, 400)
    circle = w.create_oval(190, 190, 210, 210,
                               fill='blue', width=1)

    # create list of clicks
    clicks = []
    # create function to track clicks into 'clicks'
    tracking_function = track_to_list(clicks)
    # use clicks tracker generated as click handler
    w.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: tracking_function(event))


    mainloop()
```

And the function that generates a clicks-tracking function (closure):

```
def track_to_list(lst):
    def left_mouse_click(event, robot, speed):

        # Should create and return a list
        canvas = event.widget
        canvas.create_oval(event.x - 10, event.y - 10,
                           event.x + 10, event.y + 10,
                           fill='red', width=1)
        # add tuple (x, y) to existing list
        lst.append((event.x, event.y,))
    return left_mouse_clicks
```

This will return a function with access to `lst`, and generate an event handler (like the one you had) with the added line that appends to `lst` that was given.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This was my fix after main:
def left_mouse_click(event, list):
    # Should create and return a list
    canvas = event.widget
    canvas.create_oval(event.x - 10, event.y - 10,
                       event.x + 10, event.y + 10,
                       fill='red', width=1)
    list.append((event.x, event.y))

Comment: You're shadowing the `list` built-in. How are you passing the list to the handler?